# coocox error on debug: Error: Failed to open flash driver file

Tags: stm32, ide

I got an error while press debug on CooCox CoIDE Version: 2.0.6 Build id: 20170117-2.0.6.

this is console message:

```
C:\CooCox\CoIDE_V2Beta>"C:/CooCox/CoIDE_V2Beta/bin\coflash.exe" program STM32F100RBT6B "C:/Users/Peyman/CoIDE/workspace/F100-Scartch/F100-Scartch/Debug/bin/F100-Scartch.elf" --adapter-name=ST-Link --port=SWD --adapter-clk=100000 --erase=all --driver="C:/Users/Peyman/AppData/Roaming/CooCox/CoIDE/config/flash/coocox-flash/coide_stm32f1xx_md_128k/stm32f10x_md_128.elf;"  
Error: Failed to open flash driver file
Program Download Failed !
```

I just tested other speeds. and I am using st-link version 2 embedded on STM32VLDiscovery board.

Comment: "C:/CooCox/CoIDE_V2Beta/bin\coflash.exe" You sure that last slash in the path is the correct way around?

Comment: It is from software intact..

Comment: It is not a direct answer for you but CooCox is dead. It remained unmaintained for 2 years. Try using other IDE.

Comment: @ Bumsik Kim: What you suggest??

Comment: @peyman khalili For stm32 I use Atollic True Studio. It is extremely similar, and a lot of support is live.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks god, It works by changing some configuration.
from configuration->download tab, just uncheck "auto download before debugging" like image below:
[image]

And finally:

[image]

Comment: Spent hours trying to get this same thing to work.  Thank you for finding it for us!

Answer (score 1):

Not working for me the solution above.
I had same issue but in my case the command executed automatically in the terminal was

> Blockquote
> "C:/CooCox/CoIDE_V2Beta/bin\coflash.exe" program STM32F407VG "C:/..path../ABT/Debug/bin/ABT.elf" --adapter-name=ST-Link --port=SWD --adapter-clk=1000000 --erase=affected --reset=SYSRESETREQ --driver="C:/..path../AppData/Roaming/CooCox/CoIDE/config/flash/stm32f4xx_1024.elf"

I found out that stm32f4xx_1024.elf was in a subdirectory of CooCox/CoIDE/config/flash/

Quick fix: copy and paste stm32f4xx_1024.elf from subdir to right path